# How does x position works in sprites

Tags: sprite

I am using simple Gamelab on `code.org` to create sprites. I want to create a ground for the entire screen.

So did this:

```
var ground = createSprite(0, 380,400,20);
```

This is giving me only till the half of the screen. But if I change the `x` axis value to 200, it spawns the entire screen . Can anyone explain why this happens ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ground = createSprite(200, 380, 400, 20);
```

You Have Your Number In Wrong
You X Needs To Be 200 To Be In Center